# Why a SLF4J mark is seen even though was removed

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I used SLF4J in my project but I removed all dependencies from my maven project because I do not need that.
Unfortunatelly when I run my project I see this below. I do not see any handle to SLF4J in my project.
Could you tell me why I see that?

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Comment: Maybe of your *other* dependencies uses slf4j.  Use the maven dependency checker plugin to analyze your dependencies: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html

Comment: All  my dependencies: [org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.2.4:test
org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.21:compile
junit:junit:jar:4.13:compile
org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:jar:1.4.1:compile
com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:compile]

Answer (score 1):

`org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:jar:1.4.1` depends on `slf4j`.  So that makes your project depend on `slf4j`.

I figured this out by looking at the POM files on Maven Central.

You could have done it for yourself using the Maven dependency checker plugin to analyze your dependencies:

- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html

Incidentally, this dependency looks wrong:

```
junit:junit:jar:4.13:compile
```

Unless something is really unusual about your project, it should have scope of `test` rather than `compile`.